# PHPStorm - create variable of selected text

Tags: phpstorm

I remember It's possible to create variable from selected text in storm, but I cant find how to do this.

If I have code like this:

```
$a = new SomeClass(new A(), new B());
```

...and I select text

```
new B()
```

PHPStorm should change this code to:

```
$newVawiable = new B();
$a = new SomeClass(new A(), $newVariable);
```

I remember It's possible, but I don't remember how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Refactor | Extract | Variable...`

Additional info/tutorial: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHP+Code+Refactorings+in+PhpStorm